# Nodejs + Firebase authentication

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have added firebase authentication to my node js passport  app to make it easier to sign in with Google, the following script only allows user to the dashboard page if they are authenticated, but it won't work with google authentication, can someone please help

```
 const firebase = require("firebase/app");
 require("firebase/auth");

 const firebaseConfig = {
 apiKey: "x",
 authDomain: "x",
 databaseURL: "x",
 projectId: "x",
 storageBucket: "x",
 messagingSenderId: "x",
 appId: "x",
 measurementId: "x"
};
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

  module.exports = {
  ensureAuthenticated: function(req, res, next) {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => { 
    if(req.isAuthenticated()){
        return next();
    } else if (user) {
        return next();
    } else {
    req.flash('error_msg', 'Please log in to  view this page');
    res.redirect('/users/login')
    }})}}
```